# Is Morita equivalence preserved when adjoining a variable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Let $R$ and $S$ be two rings with unity. If $R$ and $S$ are Morita equivalent (the category of $R$ modules and $S$ modules are equivalent), does this mean $R[t]$ and $S[t]$ are Morita equivalent, for some indeterminate $t$? Let's also assume $t$ commutes with elements in $R$ and $S$. If not, does anyone know conditions on $R$ and $S$ such that $R[t]$ and $S[t]$ are Morita equivalent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write $R[t]=R\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}[t]$ and $S[t]=S\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}[t]$, so what you are doing is extending the scalars from $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras to $\mathbb{Z}[t]$-algebras.

And in general scalar extension preserves Morita equivalence. You even get a little bit better, namely a Morita equivalence between $R[t]$ and $S[t]$ *over $\mathbb{Z}[t]$*, so your $R$-$S$-bimodule giving the equivalence can be taken $\mathbb{Z}[t]$-balanced, meaning that it is not just an $R\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} S^{op}$-module, but an $R\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[t]} S^{op}$-module.

Comment: Thank you very much! It also seems like this reasoning also extends to rational functions $R(t)$ and $S(t)$, unless I'm missing something? Moreover, it seems like I'm not using algebraic independence of $t$ if all I want is scalar extension. So does this result hold even if t is algebraic over $R$ or $S$?

Comment: Yes it works for any ring extension, so in particular for $\mathbb{Z}(t)$ over $\mathbb{Z}$. I'm not sure what "algebraic over $R$" means when $R$ is not commutative. But if $t$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Z}$, you still get the extension to $\mathbb{Z}[t]$.